# Symfony2 add query logging in Symfony and in csv file

Tags: mysql, logging, mysql-workbench, symfony-2.8

I need to add query logging in Symfony and in csv file. Sometime database can be busy or not available but I want to log all queries.

This log should be in csv format with columns:

-url

-datasource name

-SQL content

-parameters

-username

-start time of query execution (accuracy in ms)

-end time of query execution (accuracy in ms)

**Is any help how can I do this? or what can be done for this?**

Maybe Custom Function In which I can create the csv file with the current login user info with the url and time to execute the query to access that particular url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Symfony If you have a common SQL function which runs when each
>   query executes then this one helpful for you.

This is the thing I have implemented in my case. Hope This may help you.

```
public function execute($parameters = null)
{
if ($this->executed) {
return $this;
}
$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

$stmt = $this->execute($parameters);
$this->result = $stmt->fetchAll();
// Close cursor to allow query caching.
$stmt->closeCursor();
$this->executed = true;;

$executionEndTime = microtime(true);

//below code is added to logging for SQL queries to web server in csv format
$execution_time = $executionEndTime - $executionStartTime;
$getpageParameter = $parameters;
$getusername = $this->getUser()->getUsername();
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$parms = json_encode($getpageParameter);

$data = array(
date ("Y-m-d H:i:s")."|".$url."|".$getusername."|".$parms."|".$executionStartTime."|".$executionEndTime,
);

if(!file_exists('/../../app/logs/querylog.csv')){
$column = array(
"DATE & TIME|URL|USERNAME|PARAMETERS|START TIME|END TIME"
);
$fp = fopen('/../../app/logs/querylog.csv', 'a+');
foreach ( $column as $line ) {
$val = explode("|", $line);
fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
}

$fp = fopen('/../../app/logs/querylog.csv', 'a+');
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
$val = explode("|", $line);
fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);

return $this;
}
```